# c# Difference in behavior when call to method is uncommented in comparison to uncommenting everything in called method

Tags: c#, selenium, comments

I have an Application that uses Selenium Browser extension for chrome.

As this extension does not close the chrome browser on process exit I implemented the following code into my application:

```
static void OnProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    API.Quit();
}
class API
{
    public static IWebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver(Service(), Options());
    public static void Quit()
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(browser.CurrentWindowHandle))
        {
            browser.Quit();
            browser.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that both, `OnProcessExit` and `Quit` are in two separate classes, files and namespaces. I put them together here for easier code view.

there appears to be a bug that opens chrome when the driver is not currently open. Which is why I implemented the if case.

Now comes the weird thing:
Even when I uncomment everything within `Quit()`, the browser opens:

```
static void OnProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    API.Quit();
}
class API
{
    public static IWebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver(Service(), Options());
    public static void Quit()
    {
    /*
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(browser.CurrentWindowHandle))
        {
            browser.Quit();
            browser.Dispose();
        }
    */
    }
}
```

Whereas when I uncomment the call, the browser does not open:

```
static void OnProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //API.Quit();
}
class API
{
    public static IWebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver(Service(), Options());
    public static void Quit()
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(browser.CurrentWindowHandle))
        {
            browser.Quit();
            browser.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

My Question: Why is it that my application behaves differently wether I uncomment the call or everything in `Quit()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because static constructor.
In your first example, your pseudo-code is like this:

1. Call `API.browser = new ChromeDriver(Service(), Options());`
2. Call `API.Quit()`

In your second example nothing happens, because you are not calling static class.

To further test, try creating this method inside API class:

```
public static void FakeInit() //use to invoke static class constructor.
{
    //leave it empty.
}
```

And then call it instead of Quit:

```
API.FakeInit();
```

And you will see browser is initialized but not closed. It seems magical, but this call is actually doing this:

1. Call `API.browser = new ChromeDriver(Service(), Options());`
2. Call `API.FakeInit()` which is empty

**PS**

Main recomendation - do not use static if you are not working with extensions or marshal some unmanaged code. Just use it like this:

```
new API().Quit();
```

It is perfectly normal, you can create it at startup, pass it inside other classes, close and dispose it whenever you feel like it. And this way you will be full aware of what is going on, and why your browser is opening in some unpredicted place just because you invoked some helper method from static class. Though, I often use static for extension methods (to create DSL), I highly dislike it when using this as singleton.

Comment: interestingly with `new API().Quit();` it first opened a browser and then closed it. Not the cleanest solution but fine with me.

Comment: Yes, it is expected. But this way you will manage lifetime of API object yourself (instead of delegating it to C# static constructor behavior). For example, you can open it on startup of your application (or form), by calling something like .Open() if you don't like to open it in constructor and close it when app is shut down (or form is closing) by .Quit().